# Can I aggregate Facebook Likes, Tweets, and Google Pluses?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, google-plus, tweets

I'm building a voting application on my new website, cabinethardware.org. I'd like the voting to be done in such a way that when someone votes for a project (to receive a $1000 rebuilding grant) that they are encouraged to plug the project via social networks. My programmer has had difficulty with the application, and it occurred to me that one way of doing it is to just put like, tweet and G+ buttons on the site and add them together. So if a project gets 24 likes, 12 tweets, and 18 G+, it would have 64 votes. It doesn't bother me if someone votes on all three engines.

Before a project is eligible for a grant, it must receive 100 votes. My question is, is there a way that I can aggregate the likes, tweets, and G+ so that I can see on the backend how many votes each project has, without going to each project and adding them up by hand? Also, I'd like to display to customers the combined total.

Does anyone know of a way to combine the count of these three?

Comment: Yes. Possible. All of these services have APIs that you can query to get the number of likes for an object. What language are you using? What is your URL scheme? How are you going to display these?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response cpilko. The site is being built in Magento. You can get a look at the projects by going to http://www.cabinethardware.org/cabinet-hardware?projectid=%202. How big of a job is it to do those api's? Are you able to provide links either to them directly or to a page that explains how to do this? Thanks so much. Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Google+, you would only need to perform one API call to the Google+ APIs that would be searching the Google+ public data. Searching the Google+ public data [is demonstrated in the API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.search?query=http%253A%252F%252Fgusclass.com%252Fblog&_h=1&).

The post response contains information about reshares and +1s:

```
   "verb": "post",
   "object": {
   "objectType": "note",
    "content": "Setting up a server-side flow project that accesses Google+ data using the .NET stack can be a little tricky, I walk you through it in this blog post.",
    "url": "https://plus.google.com/109716647623830091721/posts/g8LjdGAXdDc",
    "replies": {
     "totalItems": 0,
     "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z125srm50lf1slxrd04cfftatqyoglnoqio/comments"
    },
    "plusoners": {
    "totalItems": 6,
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z125srm50lf1slxrd04cfftatqyoglnoqio/people/plusoners"
    },
    "resharers": {
     "totalItems": 0,
     "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z125srm50lf1slxrd04cfftatqyoglnoqio/people/resharers"
    },
```

For Facebook, you can use the Pages API to count likes for your page, you can [experiment with this in their API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552).

The following data shows their response data:

```
{
  "about": "Build and distribute amazing social apps on Facebook.    https://developers.facebook.com/ ", 
  "company_overview": "Facebook Platform enables anyone to build social apps on Facebook, mobile, and the web.\n\n", 
  "is_published": true, 
  "talking_about_count": 39241, 
  "username": "FacebookDevelopers", 
  "website": "http://developers.facebook.com", 
  "were_here_count": 0, 
  "category": "Product/service", 
  "id": "19292868552", 
  "name": "Facebook Developers", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers", 
  "likes": 952596, 
  "cover": {
    "cover_id": "10151121467948553", 
    "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/299374_10151121467948553_45631061_n.png", 
    "offset_y": 0
  }
}
```

Likes are just a member in the response data.

For twitter, you can query for mentions of a user with [their search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) and passing a search string for the user as @user. A count of the objects within results is going to be your mention count. The response data is a little too much to paste in here but here's [an example query using their API](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@stackoverflow).